# Custom Evaluation Metric for imbalanced Data - Inversely-Weighed Recall

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation

I'm trying to evaluate a binary classifier on imbalanced data but have trouble coming up with a metric that emphasizes on correct classification of minority class. (I have already looked at Cohen's Kappa and ROC) Accordingly, I was wondering if the following can be a valid approach:

To me, the following emphasizes on the recall rate of the minority class while also considering the rate of recall of the majority class.

[image]

Comment: What about using some weighed F score?

Comment: @DataD'oh I've seen weighed F score with the weights coming from the underlying support (like in scikit learn classification report), however I have not seen inversely weighed F score. Do you happen to have any references on this?